# How to match all comma separated strings in database?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to only get records which all receiver ids are matched, but `find_in_set` or `IN` operator in query returns all records that that contains any of the ids.

I want that only to get only records that match all of the `all_recipients` column in my database.

For example, I want to get only the record with *pid=6* in the following case:

I have the following query:

```
 SELECT * FROM `conf_event_message_recipients` WHERE receiver IN (6622,6607) AND event_id = 46
```

and the database records:

```
pid  mid    seq     receiver     all_recipients     event_id    status
8    127    9       6622         6607,6622,6624     46          2
6    127    9       6622         6607,6622          46          2
9    127    9       6622         6607,6622,6624     46          2
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: try SELECT * FROM `conf_event_message_recipients` WHERE pid=6

Comment: no i do have only receiver ids and i want to get pid

Comment: try SELECT *
FROM conf_event_message_recipients
WHERE receiver LIKE '%6607,6622%'

Comment: @krishna That will match the other two rows, too.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM conf_event_message_recipients WHERE receiver='6622'`? Also, you don't have a record with `pid=6`?

Comment: he would like to match all_recipients with receiver list, quit hard due to lack of normalization

Comment: When will people learn to NORMALIZE their data

Comment: @MarkBaker actually this is some old written code and db,and i am doing fixing it, surely i will normalize it latter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a normal equality comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM conf_event_message_recipients
WHERE all_recipients = '6607,6622'
```

or if you can't guarantee the order:

```
SELECT *
FROM conf_event_message_recipients
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(all_recipients) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(all_recipients, ',', '')) = 1
AND FIND_IN_SET('6607', all_recipients)
AND FIND_IN_SET('6622', all_recipients)
```

The first condition counts the number of commas in the field, which is one less than the number of values. Then the remaining conditions check whether each required value is in the field.

This is a very inefficient query if the table is large. You need to normalize your schema to solve this problem.

Comment: where clause for all_recipients or for receiver?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY `conf_event_message_recipients`.`seq` ASC LIMIT 0, 30' at line 5

Comment: I don't have `ORDER BY` in my answer, so I don't see how I could have that error.

Comment: I just fixed a missing parenthesis, maybe that's it.

Comment: @Barmar sorry my last question, if i have one more line e.g AND FIND_IN_SET('6624', all_recipients) and i will increase CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(all_recipients, ',', '')) = 1 to CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(all_recipients, ',', '')) = 2 ?

Comment: Right. I explained that in my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47236/discussion-between-naeem-and-barmar)

Comment: that easy solution for me, thank you very much @Barmar

Answer (score 2):

It is not pretty, but that is what happens when you store lists in a field instead of using an association/junction table.  You really should be fixing the data structure.

The following approach counts the number of matches in the string by using `find_in_set()` on each value.  It then compares to the number of items in the string, using a trick where each comma is replace by two characters, taking the length, subtracting the original length and adding one:

```
SELECT *
FROM `conf_event_message_recipients`
WHERE (find_in_set(6622, all_recipients) > 0 +
       find_in_set(6607, all_recipients) > 0
      ) = (length(replace(all_recipients, ',', ',,')) - length(all_recipients) + 1) 
WHERE event_id = 46;
```

EDIT:

There is another approach, which is also not pretty:

```
select *
from conf_event_message_recipients
where replace(replace(replace(concat(',', all_recipients, ',', ',6622,', '',
                             ) ',6607,', ''
                     ), ',', ''
             ) = '' and
      event_id = 46;
```

That is, replace each id with the empty string, then remove the commas and be sure there is nothing left.  The additional commas are to prevent "660" from matching "6607" in the replacement.

Comment: Man... this definitely is not pretty! Not to mention the possible overheat that might be coming on large data. He should DEFINITELY fix the dataset! +1 for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query :

```
SELECT * FROM `conf_event_message_recipients` WHERE all_recipients LIKE '%6622%' AND all_recipients LIKE '%6607%' AND LENGTH(all_recipients) = 9 AND event_id = 46
```

Change the value of `LENGTH(all_recipients)` as per the number of elements in `all_recipients`